# How can I reach Alitalia customer service?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, event-based-effects, covid-19, alitalia

Due to this recent situation with the coronavirus I need to cancel my plane ticket which I bought over [alitalia](https://www.alitalia.com/) website and want to see my refund options. I'm having problems reaching their customer service, from the [purchases-refunds](https://www.alitalia.com/en_en/support/utilities/buy-online/purchases-refunds.html) page they are saying that

> Refunds of the total or partial ticket price for flights canceled by
>   the passenger are permitted in accordance with the conditions of
>   carriage for the ticket bought. The conditions of carriage are shown
>   during the booking and purchase process and on the ticket receipt.
>
> Airport and security taxes are always refundable for all fares.
>
> Refunds of tickets bought on alitalia.com, through the Customer Center
>   and Alitalia ticket desks must be requested by telephoning the
>   Customer Center on 89.20.10*. For tickets issued by travel agencies,
>   the request should be sent to the agency.
>
> For refunds of airport taxes and administrative charges related to
>   tickets with a non-refundable fare, please contact: 06 65640.
>
> *From landlines, VAT included: 64 cent/min. with no connection charge. From cellphones, VAT included: TIM, Vodafone and Tre (16 cent
>    connection charge + 95 cent/min.); Wind (15 cent connection charge +
>    98 cent/min.).

Landline which I'm calling is `From Abroad +39 06 65649`, but all I get is standard machine voice (Sorry for keeping you waiting...). I could send a direct email, but they apparently don't have one for Italy, so I contacted an office in Serbia on `customer.relationsCS@alitalia.it`, also according to [customer and service](https://www.alitalia.com/en_us/support/contact-assistance/customer-center.html) link they have a USA office, but I'm not sure if this is for the US only or worldwide service.

How can I reach them to get a refund?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if the customer service line is swamped with people like you looking to change their travel plans to/from Italy.  I'd suggest to just call and wait on hold for hours, but since it's a toll number, that's only a good plan if you have money to burn.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert you are totally right, I don't have, and I know it's going to be a slow process, I was just confused about that customer service to call.

Comment: Calling them through Skype or some other VoIP service might be a drastically cheaper option, assuming they're not blacklisted there.

Comment: Hey @undercatapplaudsMonica, I hade major luck, they answered this morning, unfortunately, that is the only way you can cancel your ticket, by a phone call.

Comment: @copser Awesome to hear that! You should consider sharing your experience with others by writing an answer to your own question, I'm sure someone will find it helpful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Alitalia no longer exists, making this obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

[Alitalia - Elliott Advocacy](https://elliott.org/company-contacts/alitalia/) posts their "Executive Contacts" emails. Let know us after you email them.

> Phone Contacts
>
> Main: (212) 903 3494
> Toll Free: (800) 223-5730
> International: +39 (06) 65-631
>
> FAX 1-212-903-3568
>
> Please note the main office phone number should not be used for claims and the main office is not open to the public.
>
> ---
>
> Email Contacts
>
> customer.relationsNYC@alitalia.it
> ufficio.stampa@alitalia.it
>
> Feedback form: https://www.alitalia.com/en_us/special-pages/my-experience.html.
>
> ---
>
> Customer Service Resources
>
> For Customer Relations Issues write to:
>
> Alitalia Customer Relations, PO Box 4485, New York, NY 10163-4485
>
> ---
>
> Social Media Contacts
>
> [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/alitalia)
> [Twitter](https://twitter.com/alitalia)
>
> ---
>
> Executive Contacts
>
> **Primary Contact**
> Elizabeth Santella
> Customer Relations Manager
> 24 West 40th Street, 4th Floor
> New York,, NY 1001
> santella.elizabeth@alitalia.it
>
> **Secondary Contact**
> Benedetto Mencaroni Poiani
> VP Regional Manager Americas
> 24 West 40th Street, 4th Floor
> New York,, NY 1001
> mencaroni.benedetto@alitalia.it
>
> **Chief Executive**
> Fabio Lazzerini
> Chief Commercial Office
> Alberto Nassetti snc
> Alberto Nassetti snc
> Fiumicino , RM 00054
> +39 06 65631
> Fabio.Lazzerini@alitalia.com
>
> or try luigigubitosi@katamail.com
>
> ---
>
> Last updated: August 3, 2018.

Comment: Do you know if any of those contact options work these days? Airlines are hard to reach now and often normal communication options have been stopped.

Comment: That's true. I was crossing my fingers author can report back?

Comment: I wonder what the "potentially bad keyword" is in here..